# Where can I find documentation for the Select/When/Otherwise statement?

Tags: sas, datastep

I love using the Select/When/Otherwise statement in the data step, but my code always needs debugged before it will run properly. I never can remember the exact syntax required and SAS doesn't have very good documentation for it. (I actually can't find any mention of it except in the SCL documentation). Sometime it's because I put a semicolon after the `When` statements or forget that I need a `Do` block. Is this feature officially unsupported? If not then why isn't it documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Select/When/Otherwise documentaion](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201966.htm)

Comment: http://philihp.com/blog/2012/sas-switch-statement/ is a good explanation of how it works as well.

Comment: Obviously, I need to use better search terms. This page isn't in the search results for either "Select When" or "Select When Otherwise" on the SAS site. However, it's the first result when searching for "Select Statement". Thanks for your help.